recurrence relation (related to plane-search accelerated GD)
In the original proof for acceleration (using plane-search), the following step (from (2.6) to (2.7)) starts with
$$
\sum_{I=1}^N \frac{v_i}{\sqrt{v_i - v_{i+1}}} \leq C
$$
and concludes that $v_{N+1} \leq C^2/N^3$ (here, $C$ stands in place of various problem-related constants, which I don't think should affect controlling the series sum).
Since the final result is relatively simple, I think I'm missing a technique in controlling such a recurrence. So far, I've tried using HM - GM - AM - QM, or just squaring both sides, but I'm not getting anything useful.
